# iOS - Swift: How to hide ASScrollNode vertical scroll indicator in Texture/AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I use `Texture` to create my new application but I stuck in how to hide the scroll indicator in `ASScrollNode` while `ASScrollNode` does not have the `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` property like in `UIScrollView`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: ASScrollNode.view should be UIScrollView. Check it pls.

Comment: @Bimawa Oh, thank you for that. It's not showing in code completion. It works!!!